# Find the expression for the linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> A real linear space $W$ of dimension $2$ is considered, with a basis $B = \{w_1, w_2\}$. Find the expression $f(x)$ of the
> linear mapping $f : \mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow W$ whose kernel is the subspace $N = {(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) : x_1 + 3x_2 + x_4 = 0}$ and satisfies the
> condition $f(0, 0, 0, 1) = w_1 − w_2$.

What I tried so far was considering the kernel: $$x_1=-3x_2-x_4\Rightarrow (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(-3x_2-x_4,x_2,0,x_4)$$ which is $$=x_2(-3,1,0,0)+x_4(-1,0,0,1)$$ which then we have $$N=\{(-3,1,0,0), (-1,0,0,1)\}$$ and now I'm guessing we have to consider $f(0,0,0,1)=w_1-w_2$ but I don't know how to continue with that

Answer (score 1):

If $M=span \{(1,3,0,1)\}$ then $\mathbb R^{4}$ is the direct sum of $N$ amd $M$. We want $f$ to be $0$ on $N$, so we only have to find the value of $f(1,3,0,1)=c$, say. Now any point $(x,y,z,w)$ can be written as $a( 1,3,0,1)+v$ where $a$ is chosen such that $v=(x,y,z,w)- a(1,3,0,1)\in N$. This means $x-a+3(y-3a)+w-a=0$ , so $a=\frac 1 {11}[x+3y-9+w]$. We now have $f((x,y,z,w))=\frac 1 {11}[x+3y+w]c$. Note that $f(0,0,0,1)=\frac 1 {11}f(1,3,0,1))$. So we want $w_1-w_2=-4f(1,3,0,1))=-4c$. Finally, $$f((x,y,z,w))=[x+3y+w] (w_1-w_2)].$$